# How to add multiple model attributes into one model attribute?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I have different functions which returns and stores values into a model attribute. But now I have to pass it as single model attribute...Is it possible???? Any kind of help will be appreciated

I so how can I add **place**,**type**,**time** into one???

```
    MyList1 mylist1 = new MyList1();
    model.addAttribute("place", mylist1.getTypeList("mydbname"));

    MyList2 mylist2 = new MyList2();
    model.addAttribute("type", mylist2.getTimeList("mydbname"));

    MyList3 mylist3=new MyList3();
    model.addAttribute("time",mylist3.getCrimeList("mydbname"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a POJO with the place, type and time as properties then create a new instance of that pojo then add that instance to the model this way you will have only one model attribute.

**POJO**

```
public class ModelAttrs{
    String place;
    String type;
    String time;

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

To add the attribute.

```
ModelAttrs modelAttrs = new ModelAttrs();
modelAttrs.setPlace(mylist1.getTypeList("mydbname"));
modelAttrs.setType(mylist2.getTimeList("mydbname"));
modelAttrs.setTime(mylist3.getCrimeList("mydbname"));
model.addAttribute("modelAttrs",modelAttrs);
```